# Delphi 2006 with TWebBrowser and pdfMake

Tags: javascript, delphi, pdfmake

I'm trying to use the `pdfMake` APIs in an HTML page displayed on a Delphi 2006 `TWebBrowser` page.

It works fine but when i execute `pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download();` the pdf file, after downloaded in an unknown directory, the file is opened automatically.
How can i disable this "autoopen" procedure?

***My delphi code:***

```
procedure TForm1.BtnOpenClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  fileName: string;
begin
  fileName := 'file:\\' + GetCurrentDir + '\source.html';
  WebBrowser1.Navigate(fileName);
end;
```

p.s. the `download()` function is executed when the HTML body is loaded.

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, you have no control over this. The `download()` function relies on the [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) script, which resorts to opening the document in a new browser window if it can't gain direct access to the client machine's file system. The user would have to save the document manually in that case.

Comment: @RemyLebeau but if i execute `download()` in the chrome console the file will be just downloaded on my downloads directory.

Comment: read my previous comment again, and go look at the script I linked to. It tries to access the filesystem first, and if it can't, it opens a new browser window. It handles different browsers in different ways. `TWebBrowser` is a wrapper for Internet Explorer, not Chrome.

Comment: Now i'm callig from Java Sctipt source th `navigator.msSaveBlob()` (by TWebBrowser yet) and it still show me the "save as" dialog... how can i disable it?